# Is C++ local static variable initialization thread-safe in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2015

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Magic statics (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm)
are supported on VS2015

However testing the following code in debug x64 Vs2015 Update 3

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 5

class Sleeper
{
public:
    Sleeper()
    {
        std::cout << "Sleeper \n";
        Sleep(100000);
    }
};

DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    std::cout << "Sleeper Start" << (int)lpParam << "\n";
    static Sleeper s;
    std::cout << "Sleeper Done" << (int)lpParam << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    DWORD   dwThreadIdArray[MAX_THREADS];
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[MAX_THREADS];

    // Create MAX_THREADS worker threads.

    for (int i = 0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        // Create the thread to begin execution on its own.
        hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(
            NULL,                   // default security attributes
            0,                      // use default stack size  
            MyThreadFunction,      // thread function name
            (LPVOID)i,               // argument to thread function 
            0,                     // use default creation flags 
            &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   // returns the thread identifier 

                                    // Check the return value for success.
                                    // If CreateThread fails, terminate execution. 
                                    // This will automatically clean up threads and memory. 
        if (hThreadArray[i] == NULL)
        {
            ExitProcess(3);
        }
    } // End of main thread creation loop.

      // Wait until all threads have terminated.
    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close all thread handles and free memory allocations.
    for (int i = 0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

gives output

> Sleeper Start0 Sleeper Sleeper Start2 Sleeper Start3 Sleeper Start1
>   Sleeper Start4

Which indicates that initializing static variable s is actually not thread safe.

Comment: As long as vs2015 claims to be c++11 standard compliant, it should be thread safe. _"Which indicates that initializing static variable s is actually not thread safe."_ What let's you doubt about it? The function can be called multiple times from different threads though.

Comment: How does this show initialization isn't thread safe? Your prints are confusing, but it seems thread 0 prints first and then creates the sleeper, and all others print the "Sleeper StartN" and stall, waiting for the static sleeper to be created. Are there some "Sleeper Done" prints eventually, to complete the picture?

Comment: @NicolBolas of course. But how does the print show more threads are initializing it? Note that the word "Sleeper" is printed both in `MyThreadFunction` and in `Sleeper`'s constructor, which is confusing. Changing the print in the constructor would probably made things clearer, and prove it was only called once.

Comment: @eran: Yes, the naming is very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake. Removing the word sleeper from MyThreadFunction gives the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. The test was wrong. Removing the word sleeper from MyThreadFunction shows the expected output

> Start1 Sleeper Start4 Start3 Start0 Start2 Done3 Done1 Done0 Done2
>   Done4